# How to combine two lists into a json containing a dict inside having a key-value pair in python (for django)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list

Hey guys I am trying to combine two lists, specifically `tag_names` and `tag_slugs` into this format for using it in frontend. I don't know which is the efficient way, but this is how I need.

```
tags: {
    name: tag_name, slug:slug_name,
    name: 2nd, slug: 2nd slug,
    ...
}
```

This is what I have now.

```
def get_tags(self, post):
    tags_name = post.tags.names()
    tags_slug = post.tags.slugs()
    print(tags_name, tags_slug)
```

These are two querysets.

```
<QuerySet ['one', 'two', 'One']> <QuerySet ['one', 'two', 'one_1']>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tags` dictionary is invalid, you can't have the same key multiple times. So let's assume we structure it like this:

```
tags: [
    {'name': 'tag_name', 'slug': 'slug_name'},
    {'name': '2nd_tag_name', 'slug': '2nd_slug_name'},
    ...
]
```

This is a list of dictionaries.

Then you can do:

```
def get_tags(self, post):
    tags_name = post.tags.names()
    tags_slug = post.tags.slugs()
    l1 = list(tags_name.values_list('...', flat=True))
    l2 = list(tags_slug.values_list('...', flat=True))
    tags = [{'name': zipped[0], 'slug': zipped[1]} for zipped in zip(l1, l2)]
    print(tags)
```

You mentioned `tags_name` and `tags_slug` are QuerySets, so you must make sure to flatten them with `values_list('...', flat=True)`. I don't know what the attribute of the model is so you would need to replace `...` with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I was having confusion with the line `values_list` and `flat=True`. Thanks for clearing that out too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a list of dicts:

```
new_list = {'tags':[{'name': n, 'slug': s} for n, s in zip(list(tags_name), list(tags_slug))]}
```

Result:

```
{'tags': [{'name': 'one', 'slug': 'one'},
  {'name': 'two', 'slug': 'two'},
  {'name': 'One', 'slug': 'one_1'}]}
```